# Create an IObservable from a method and others

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, system.reactive

Is the code below correctly written to return an IObservable in terms of Rx library? It seems to work correct, but wondering I'm using it correctly.

```
private IObservable<SearchResult[]> Search(string query)
{
    return Observable.Create((IObserver<SearchResult[]> observer)=>
        {
            List<SearchResult> result = new List<SearchResult>();
            foreach (TestsGroupMeta group in Engine.Groups)
            {
                string name = group.ToString();
                if (name.IndexOf(query, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
                {
                    result.Add(new SearchResult{ Name = name, Type = "Group"});
                }

                foreach (TestMethodMeta method in group.Methods)
                {
                    name = method.ToString();
                    if (name.IndexOf(query, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
                    {
                        result.Add(new SearchResult {Name = name, Type = "Method"});
                    }
                }
            }

            observer.OnNext(result.ToArray());
            observer.OnCompleted();

            return () => {};
        });
}
```

The usage is like this.

```
private void SearchForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textChanged = Observable.FromEventPattern<EventArgs>(txtQuery, "TextChanged")
        .Select(_ => ((TextBox)_.Sender).Text);

    var searchResult = from query in textChanged
        where query.Length >= 3
        from result in Search(query)
        select result;

    _resultsWatcher = searchResult
        .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200))
        .ObserveOn(lvResults)
        .Subscribe(resuts =>
            {
                lvResults.BeginUpdate();
                lvResults.Items.Clear();
                foreach (SearchResult result in resuts)
                {
                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(result.Name);
                    item.SubItems.Add(result.Type);
                    lvResults.Items.Add(item);
                }

                lvResults.EndUpdate();
            });
}
```

Also, Is there a way to create an IObservable from such a method?

```
Task<List<SearchResult>> Search(string query){...}
```

Or, what would be other approaches to create an asynchronous search over a large dataset and have an IObservable from it.

Thx

Comment: Try it [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Throttle would mean results are lost. The `.ToArray() ` does nothing, the usage of the List/Array means that you lose the ability to stream the data (you get all the results in one go once your worker has finished).

Comment: Mixing View logic with Model logic (poor separation of concern).

Comment: Guys I'm not asking about View and Model logic, or List/array, the question was purely about RX and the way to create an asynchronous method that would comply to RX concepts. But thx for the observations, I'll check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create an observable from task as such,

```
Task<List<SearchResult>> SearchAsync(string query){...}

var observable = Observable.FromAsync<List<SearchResult>>(()=> SearchAsync(query));
```

If your function is returning just 1 result in the future consider using Task instead?

```
public async Task<SearchResult[]> SearchAsync(string query){ }
```